# Transferring $_POST values to jQuery initiated popup window through ajax not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

The website I'm working on has a document submission form for users to enter in their details and the details of the document they're submitting, however the client requested that in the middle of the form, there is a Preview button that when clicked, has a popup page (not a new tab) that displays the document details & author details. This is an added function in addition to the standard submitting process at the end of the form.

Now I've gone off some tutorials on this site, but it still doesn't seem to be working for me. Can anyone please advise what I'm missing?

html (summarized)

```
<form id="document-submit-form" method="post" action="index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="text" name="documentTitle" class="longInputBox" id="documentTitleInput" value=""   required   />
   <input type="text" name="authorsNameOne" id="authorsNameOneInput" value="" class="authorsNameInput"  required  />
</form>
```

jQuery (summarized - at the end of validation)

```
   $("#documentPreviewSubmit").click(function(event) {

   event.preventDefault();

   var $title = escape($('#documentTitleInput').val());
   var $author = escape($('#authorsNameOne').val());

   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "preview.php",
     data: { documentTitle: $title, authorsNameOne: $author }
   }).done(function( msg ) {
     var url = "preview.php";
     var windowName = "popUp";
     var windowSize = "width=495,height=680";

     window.open(url, windowName, windowSize);
   });

});
```

preview.php (summarized)

```
<?php
      echo '<h1>'.$_POST['documentTitle'].'</h1>'."\n";
      echo '<h2>'.$_POST['authorsNameOne'].'</h2>'."\n";
?>
```

However, even though the popup window appears, no data is picked up.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: From your problem description, it doesn't sound like you really need AJAX -- although you could use it. AJAX is used when you need the server to do something to the user-provided data (such as looking up something in MySQL) -- and you may not need to do that here. Check out my solution below just using only javascript/jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling preview.php two times: One when sending POST data and the other is when you're showing its contents in the popup window (it's not getting any POST data).

The easiest way is to create a PHP Session, store the values in $_SESSION variables (inside a processData.php script) and show them when you call preview.php. Something like:

```
/* This is the processData.php */
session_name('AnySessionName');
session_start();

$_SESSION = $_POST;
```

Then use a preview.php file like:

```
/* This is the preview.php */
session_name('AnySessionName');
session_start();


// Here you can show your preview page, using $_SESSION['documentTitle'] instead of $_POST['documentTitle']

// After using this, destroy the session.
unset($_SESSION['documentTitle']); // Repeat for any parameter used
session_destroy();
```

This way, you script would be like:

```
$("#documentPreviewSubmit").click(function(event) {

   event.preventDefault();

   var $title = escape($('#documentTitleInput').val());
   var $author = escape($('#authorsNameOne').val());

   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "processData.php",
     data: { documentTitle: $title, authorsNameOne: $author }
   }).done(function( msg ) {
     var url = "preview.php";
     var windowName = "popUp";
     var windowSize = "width=495,height=680";

     window.open(url, windowName, windowSize);
   });
```

Comment: Because the popup window is not part of the form, it's another request. He could use GET as you suggested, but it has limitations in length. Maybe it's useful for his purposes, though.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it doesn't pick any data because you don't pass any(you do in the ajax call, which is a separate request that doesn't know nothing about your next window.open call).
You should pass the variables in the $_GET in your case:

```
var url = "preview.php?title=" + $title + '&author=' + $author;
var windowName = "popUp";
var windowSize = "width=495,height=680";

window.open(url, windowName, windowSize);
```

Then in preview.php you will pick them up like:

```
$title = isset($_GET['title']) ? $_GET['title'] : null;
$author = isset($_GET['author']) ? $_GET['author'] : null;
```

Next, the alternative.
You could, however do something like:

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "preview.php",
 data: { documentTitle: $title, authorsNameOne: $author }
 }).done(function( msg ) {
   $('#someHiddenDiv').html(msg).show();
  });
```

Where `#someHiddenDiv` is an absolute positioned div where you spit the content of your `preview.php` page that has processed the ajax call.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, it certainly works, and you identified why my original information wasn't appearing when I referred to preview.php the second time when opening it in a window which was a good lesson learned, but @Alejandro Iván has mentioned why this particular solution doesn't quite fit my project, the actual amount of values I need to pass is quite a few (I just summarized  my code and mentioned two values that need to be passed), which I can't risk being cut of in a long url. Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

AJAX might be overkill here. All you need to do is take values from DOM elements, insert them into a hidden DIV, and display the hidden DIV as, for example, a lightbox.

You can use `jQueryUI's .dialog()` method to do this, without involving AJAX at all.

*Note that, like jQuery, jQueryUI (and its stylesheet) must be referenced/loaded before the code is used.*

AJAX would only be useful if you needed to somehow process the data (eg. take the user-provided data and look up something in MySQL and then return different data). Since you appear to be using only the data the user provided himself, you can just do this with javascript/jQuery

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/6EPQJ/)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            ul{list-style-type: none;}
        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $( "#preview" ).dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    height: 300,
                    width: 350,
                    modal: true,
                    title: 'Document Preview:',
                    buttons: {
                        'Do Something': function() {
                            // code to do something upon dlg close 
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                        },
                        Close: function() {
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                        }
                    }
                });

                $('#btn_pv').click(function() {
                    var dt = $('#documentTitleInput').val();
                    var an = $('#authorsNameOneInput').val();
                    var pv = '';
                    pv += '<h2>' +dt+ '</h2>';
                    pv += '<h2>' +an+ '</h2>';
                    $("#preview").html(pv);
                    $("#preview").dialog('open');
                });

            }); //END $(document).ready()

        </script>
    </head>
<body>

    <form id="document-submit-form" method="post" action="index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <ul>
            <li>
                Document Title:<br />
                <input type="text" name="documentTitle" class="longInputBox" id="documentTitleInput" value=""   required   />
            </li>
            <li>
                Author's Name:<br />
                <input type="text" name="authorsNameOne" id="authorsNameOneInput" value="" class="authorsNameInput"  required  />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
    <br />
    <input type="button" id="btn_pv" value="Preview" />

    <div id="preview"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

---

HOWEVER, if you wanted to do this using AJAX, you would modify your button click event something like this:

```
$('#btn_pv').click(function() {
    var dt = $('#documentTitleInput').val();
    var an = $('#authorsNameOneInput').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "your_php_file.php",
            data: 'docTitle=' +dt+ '&aName=' +an,
            success: function(pv) {
                    $("#preview").html(pv);
                    $( "#preview" ).dialog({
                        autoOpen: true,
                        height: 300,
                        width: 350,
                        modal: true,
                        title: 'Document Preview:',
                        buttons: {
                            'Do Something': function() {
                                // code to do something upon dlg close 
                                $(this).dialog('close');
                            },
                            Close: function() {
                                $(this).dialog('close');
                            }
                        }
                    }); //end .dialog()
            } //END success fn
        }); //END $.ajax

    //var pv = '';
    //pv += '<h2>' +dt+ '</h2>';
    //pv += '<h2>' +an+ '</h2>';
    $("#preview").html(pv);
    $("#preview").dialog('open');
});
```

---

The PHP file, `your_php_file.php` (or whatever you want to call it) would be:

```
<?php
    $dtit = $_POST['docTitle'];
    $anam = $_POST['aName'];

    $r = '<h2>' .$dtit. '</h2>';
    $r .='<h2>' .$anam. '</h2>';

    echo $r;
```

If you change the name of the PHP file (I hope you do), remember to also change how it is called in the AJAX routine above.

Comment: This is a great suggestion, I've had fun playing around with jQuery UI which I haven't heard of before, but I think the solution I've picked will be better for future developements for this particular project, particularly with eventually turning the newly generated page into a pdf which mostly seems to depend on a seperate page/window opened, rather than a hidden div displayed. Cheers though!